# inhabilitar campo formulario para ingresar valor fijo

Tags: php, html5

Tengo un formulario donde el id del empleado tiene que ser el del empleado que tiene iniciada la sesión. Lo tengo de la siguiente manera porque quiero que cuando un empleado organice una reunión, pueda ver su propio id insertado y no la organice con el id de otro por error.

```
$idEmpleado = $_SESSION['idEmpleado'];

 <div class="campo-alta-empleados">
            <label for="idEmpleadoOrganizador">Organizado por (ID):</label>
            <input type="text" disabled name="idEmpleadoOrganizador" id="idEmpleadoOrganizador" value="<?php echo $idEmpleado?>">
        </div>
```

Esto queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que al mandarlo al controlador, por alguna razón no lo coge e inserta ese valor a null. Este es mi controlador:

```
$idEmpleadoOrganizador = $reunion->setIdEmpleadoOrganizador($_POST['idEmpleado']);
            $asunto = $reunion->setAsunto($_POST['asunto']);
            $sala = $reunion->setSala($_POST['sala']);
            $fecha = $reunion->setFecha($_POST['fecha']);
            $inicio = $reunion->setInicio($inicioFormateado);
            $fin = $reunion->setFin($finFormateado);
            $observaciones = $reunion->setObservaciones($_POST['observaciones']);

            $reunionDao->insertarReunion($reunion);
```

Parece que el problema está en el disabled del formulario, porque si lo quito, funciona perfectamente. Alguien conoce alguna otra forma de dejar el campo inaccesible?

Comment: Trata de poner en campo en readonly, ya que al poner un campo disabled y al querer tratar pasar su valor éste no será reconocido.

Comment: Funciona perfecto!! Muchísimas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pongo mi comentario como respuesta para que pueda ser de utilidad para otros usuarios.

Tu problema es que tratas de pasar el valor de un input que esta en `disabled`. Al tratar de mostrar dicho valor en el `controller` no lo reconocerá.

```
<input type="text" disabled name="idEmpleadoOrganizador" id="idEmpleadoOrganizador" value="<?php echo $idEmpleado?>">
//                  ~~~~~~
```

Para solucionar esto, basta con cambiar tu input a `readonly`, para que el valor del input llegue a tu `controller`, a la vez que dicho campo no será modificable.

```
<input type="text" readonly name="idEmpleadoOrganizador" id="idEmpleadoOrganizador" value="<?php echo $idEmpleado?>">
//                  ~~~~~~
```